# Rails Action cable : how to pass room id from client channel.js to server channel.rb securely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I want to pass my room id which is basically a table row id to the server so it can create new user and stream connection particularly from it

```
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    project = Project.find(params[:id])

    stream_from "chat:#{project.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

chat_channel.rb

chat_channel.js

```
import consumer from "./consumer"



    consumer.subscriptions.create({channel:"ChatChannel" ,  id: how_to_get_project_id_here } , {
      connected() {
        // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    
      },
    
      disconnected() {
        // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
      },
    
      received(data) {
        if (data['body'] === ''){
          
        }else{
          this.appendLine(data);
    
        }
        
      },
    
      appendLine(data) {
     
        const html = this.createLine(data);
        const element = document.querySelector(".chatroom");
        element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
      },
    
      createLine(data) {
        return `
        <div class="message_box">
        <div class="message_wrapper">
            <div class="message_sender">
                <p>${data["sender"]}</p> 
    
             </div>
             <div class="message_body">
                 <p>
                     ${data["body"]}
    
                 </p>
             </div>
        </div>
       
    </div>
        `
      }
    });
```

I checked other methods on internet most of them includes data attributes which is unsafe.

other way include storing it in cookie which again looks counter intuitive as cookie can be changed easily by user

Comment: what do you concern about ? a user can join a project room chat in which he has not permission to join ?

Comment: @LamPhan Yes he can change the data attribute of the form to send message to a different Project

Comment: but before send message, he need to connect to the project channel, right ? you could validate user and reject the connection if that user not belongs to the project.

Comment: but any user can send a message to any project channel room